# Tracking down optimizer issues in durandal.js

Tags: durandal

I have a large application with a few hundred viewmodels but when I run the optimizer it doesn't combine them into the main-built.js, it just clears out the file.

Is there any way to get the optimizer to give you more information on where it had an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are all the options available

1. **--mode** Indicates whether the optimizer should only 'generate' the r.js config or actually 'build' the optimized JS application. Default value build
2. **--source** The path to the folder which contains the application source.
3. **--config** The path to the customized r.js configuration file to be used as a base for the generated configuration.
4. **--verbose** Indicates that verbose console logging should be used. Default value false
5. **--loader** Indicates which script loader to optimize for 'almond' or 'require'. Default value almond
6. **--plugin** The view plugin used to optimize views into the final build file. Default value text
7. **--pluginExtension** The view file extension. Default value .html

Using the optimizer is like so:

```
optimizer.exe --source c:\project1\app\ --mode generate
```

So, maybe you should try this:

```
optimizer.exe --verbose true
```

and if that doesn't work.. then you can always pull down the source and try and debug it locally.