# Durandal.js optimizer generating empty main-built.js

Tags: requirejs, durandal

I am trying to [optimize my Durandal app](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Optimizing-On-Dot-Net/) but the main-built.js is blank.

I have tried running `node r.js -o app.build.js`  and this threw an error saying that it could not find a file. I added these paths in my main.js file and each individual error went away. However, now the command above just exits with "Tracing dependencies for: durnadal/amd/almond.custom" and the file is still blank.

**Question**:  Which libraries need to go into the paths below? It seems to the external libraries that I use in my index.html and it needs the exact file name?

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "text": "durandal/amd/text",
        "breeze": "lib/breeze/breeze.min",
        "knockout": "lib/knockout/knockout.mapping-latest",
    }
});
```

When I run Optimizer.exe in the Durandal AMD folder main-built.js is blank. This is the app.build.js file that is generated - any help appreciated on how to get more verbose logging with Almond. I have tried `optimizer -verbose true` with no luck.

```
{
  "name": "durandal/amd/almond-custom",
  "inlineText": true,
  "stubModules": [
    "durandal/amd/text"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "text": "durandal/amd/text"
  },
  "baseUrl": "C:\\DNNDev.me\\DesktopModules\\Framework.App\\App",
  "mainConfigFile": "C:\\DNNDev.me\\DesktopModules\\Framework.App\\App\\main.js",
  "include": [
    "text!about.html",
    "about",
    "appNavigation",
    "config",
    "text!dareAdd.html",
    "dareAdd",
    "text!dareDetail.html",
    "dareDetail",
    "text!dareList.html",
    "dareList",
    "text!dareListItem.html",
    "dataContext",
    "dataService",
    "dataServiceHelper",
    "enums",
    "errorWatcher",
    "text!home.html",
    "home",
    "text!index.html",
    "text!indextopcoat.html",
    "indextopcoat",
    "text!kendoIndex.html",
    "text!loader.html",
    "logger",
    "text!login.html",
    "login",
    "main-built",
    "main",
    "text!menu.html",
    "model",
    "text!navbar.html",
    "text!notifyOfError.html",
    "notifyOfError",
    "text!privacy.html",
    "privacy",
    "text!profile.html",
    "profile",
    "text!shell.html",
    "shell",
    "text!signup.html",
    "signup",
    "text!testpage.html",
    "testpage",
    "uiutilities",
    "userState",
    "viewModelHelper",
    "text!walkthrough.html",
    "walkthrough",
    "widgetService",
    "css/telerik/js/kendo.dataviz.min",
    "css/topcoat/js/hello",
    "css/topcoat/js/hello.min",
    "css/topcoat/js/index",
    "css/topcoat/lib/hello",
    "css/topcoat/lib/vendor/ender.min",
    "css/topcoat/lib/vendor/fastclick",
    "durandal/app",
    "durandal/composition",
    "durandal/events",
    "durandal/http",
    "text!durandal/messageBox.html",
    "durandal/messageBox",
    "durandal/modalDialog",
    "durandal/system",
    "durandal/viewEngine",
    "durandal/viewLocator",
    "durandal/viewModel",
    "durandal/viewModelBinder",
    "durandal/widget",
    "durandal/plugins/router",
    "durandal/transitions/entrance",
    "js/cordova",
    "js/facebookscript",
    "lib/bootstrap/bootstrap",
    "lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min",
    "lib/breeze/breeze.debug",
    "lib/breeze/breeze.intellisense",
    "lib/breeze/breeze.min",
    "lib/breeze/q",
    "lib/breeze/q.min",
    "lib/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.intellisense",
    "lib/jquery/jquery-2.0.3",
    "lib/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min",
    "lib/knockout/knockout-2.3.0.debug",
    "lib/knockout/knockout-2.3.0",
    "lib/knockout/knockout.mapping-latest.debug",
    "lib/knockout/knockout.mapping-latest",
    "lib/knockout/knockout.validation.debug",
    "lib/knockout/knockout.validation",
    "lib/moment/moment",
    "lib/moment/moment.min",
    "lib/ratchet/ratchet",
    "lib/sammy/sammy-0.7.4",
    "lib/sammy/sammy-0.7.4.min",
    "lib/toastr/toastr",
    "lib/toastr/toastr.min"
  ],
  "exclude": [],
  "keepBuildDir": true,
  "optimize": "uglify2",
  "out": "C:\\DNNDev.me\\DesktopModules\\Framework.App\\App\\main-built.js",
  "pragmas": {
    "build": true
  },
  "wrap": true,
  "insertRequire": [
    "main"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your path you are setting your reference to knockout equal to the mapping plugin, which is no bueno.

As shown in this answer, [Durandal.js optimizer not working (empty main-built.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686822/durandal-js-optimizer-not-working-empty-main-built-js) you can run it like Rainer shows and you should see a more specific error.

One thing that I found - if you remove a view model or use a folder or directory as a purgatory (about to be deleted) those files may not be used in your app but if they are in the file structure they will still be evaluated by the optimizer.

**EDIT**

Check here for more info on the optimizer - [Tracking down optimizer issues in durandal.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671109/tracking-down-optimizer-issues-in-durandal-js?rq=1)

Also, are you building debug or release?  Are you targeting the correct one?  [durandal optimizer references wrong path when building it as a post build process in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684040/durandal-optimizer-references-wrong-path-when-building-it-as-a-post-build-proces?rq=1)

Also, if you are referencing Knockout.js, I think you mean to reference "lib/knockout/knockout-2.3.0" not the knockout mapping plugin.

Unless I am missing something you shouldn't have to add those paths to your main.js file.  Breeze and Knockout should be referenced already.  Depending on your project type, your editor, etc... it is probably bundled in your App.Start folder under DurandalBundleConfig.  If it is not then are you just referencing the libraries from your index.html?

Move them into the bundle config if that is the case (something like this) -

```
  bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
      .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
      .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.min.js")
      .Include("~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js")
      .Include("~/Scripts/sammy-{version}.js")
      .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
      .Include("~/Scripts/knockout-bootstrap.min.js")
      .Include("~/Scripts/Q.js")
      .Include("~/Scripts/breeze.debug.js")
    );
```

Note that you need to load Q prior to Breeze, as Breeze depends on Q.

Comment: Hmm - please see the top of my question - I have already tried that and resolved some issues, but there are no more error messages... any other suggestions?

Comment: Where are you loading Breeze and Knockout and referencing them?

Comment: Thanks for your help - I am NOT using MVC - this is a standalone PhoneGap app using Durandal (ie. no Bundles). Knockout, Toastr and Breeze are all registered directly in the index.html (is this correct?)

Comment: Well I am no PhoneGap expert but it still looks like you are registering Knockout Mapping as Knockout instead of the base library.